# Cannot connect LG G3 Android phone to Linux PC

Tags: linux, usb, android, arch-linux, mtp

I just want to access the files on my Verizon LG G3 phone from my Linux PC.

I have `adb` installed and I followed this [ArchLinux tutorial](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Android#Connecting_to_a_real_device_-_Android_Debug_Bridge_.28ADB.29) but `adb devices` outputs the following:

```
[grease-lightning]/home/lucas$ adb devices
* daemon not running. starting it now on port 5037 *
* daemon started successfully *
List of devices attached
```

I also followed this [xda-developers tutorial](http://forum.xda-developers.com/lg-g3/general/guide-connecting-lg-g3-to-linux-adb-aka-t2821673) but the MTP tool does not seem to detect my device properly.

I have usb debug on, and MTP mode on, (via `Settings > Storage > usb/pc connection > "MTP" (default was PTP)` on my Android phone).

I also tried running the commands `mtp-detect` with [this output](http://codepad.org/nrAOwaiR) and `mtp-connect` with [this output](http://codepad.org/fKRH62qx), but I cannot seem to access the file system. Most notably, it seems that the vender and product id are not detected, as quoted here from the `mtp-detect` output:

```
Device 0 (VID=1004 and PID=627f) is UNKNOWN.
Please report this VID/PID and the device model to the libmtp development team
   Found 1 device(s):
   1004:627f @ bus 3, dev 25
```

As instructed in the `xda` tutorial, here are the contents of my udev file:

```
[my-pc]/home/lucas$ cat /etc/udev/rules.d/51-android.rules
SUBSYSTEM=="usb",ATTR{idVendor}=="1004",ATTR{Product}=="627f",MODE="0666"
```

and here is the `lsusb` info for clarification:

```
[grease-lightning]/home/lucas$ lsusb | grep LG
Bus 003 Device 039: ID 1004:627f LG Electronics, Inc.
```

So, after trying these tutorials using the mtp and adb approaches, how can I connect to the files/media on my Android phone? Any suggestions?

I am using ArchLinux if that matters, and I would prefer a simple CLI approach to accessing the files on my phone.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with my nexus 5 on ubuntu. It was a problem of permissions; the device file was root for some reason.

What does this yield?

```
ls -l /dev/bus/usb/003/039
```

If it's owned by group root and owner root then an elegant solution would be to add the group entry plugdev in your udev, which you should already be a member of

```
SUBSYSTEM=="usb",ATTR{idVendor}=="1004",ATTR{Product}=="627f",GROUP="plugdev",MODE="0666"
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, and this may be the problem, but Arch does not have a `plugdev` group. I tried creating a similar udev group with the contents `SUBSYSTEM=="usb",ATTR{idVendor}=="1004",ATTR{Product}=="627f",TAG+='uaccess'`, but that didn't work either. Any suggestions would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I think I resolved this by using the [jmtpfs](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/jmtpfs/) tool. I ran the commands `jmtp -l`, which output this:

```
Device 0 (VID=1004 and PID=627f) is UNKNOWN.
Please report this VID/PID and the device model to the libmtp development team
Available devices (busLocation, devNum, productId, vendorId, product, vendor):
3, 48, 0x627f, 0x1004, UNKNOWN, UNKNOWN
```

Although it didn't recognize my device, I was still able to mount it with `jmtpfs ~/temp/lucas-android` then access the filesystem as usual.

BTW, I [filed a request](https://sourceforge.net/p/libmtp/feature-requests/132/) to add my device with libmtp on sourceforge